# realm query object by a deeply nested object

Tags: android, realm

I'm planning to use realm database, I have a structure similar to this:

class A:
-id
-List of B objects

class B:
-id
-C object

class C:
-id

Is it possible in realm to query A based on C.id ? Thanks!

Comment: The answer is "kind of". You can check if there are any As that have at least 1 Bs where at least 1 of C is "something".

Comment: Can I check if there are any As that have any Bs where at least one of Cs has an id of something?  

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's `realm.where(A.class).equalTo("bs.c.id", "idOfC").findAll()`. Link queries translate to `ANY`, I like to think of it as "has at least one of where".

Comment: Thanks! Please write that in an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible in realm to query A based on C.id ?

The answer is "kind of". You can check if there are any As that have at least 1 Bs where at least 1 of C is "something".

> Can I check if there are any As that have any Bs where at least one of Cs has an id of something?

It's `realm.where(A.class).equalTo("bs.c.id", "idOfC").findAll()`.

Link queries in Realm's Java API translate to `ANY`, I like to think of it as "has at least one of where".